# Laravel 5.1 - Connecting to MySQL Database (MAMP)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, pdo, mamp

There are topics online that are discussing this problem however, I couldn't find any tidy explanation of the problem or any solid answers for the question. What I am trying to achieve is connecting Laravel 5.1 to MySQL Database of MAMP.

---

In my ***config>app.php:***

```
   'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


   'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost:8889',
        'database'  => 'test',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

In my ***.env:***

```
      DB_HOST=localhost
      DB_DATABASE=test
      DB_USERNAME=root
      DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I also have ***.env.example:*** (which I believe has no functionality)

```
      DB_HOST=localhost
      DB_DATABASE=homestead
      DB_USERNAME=homestead
      DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I also have `create_users_table.php` and `create_password_resets_table.php` in my ***database>migrations*** (even though I did not run any migration:make)

---

MAMP is directing and running the server successfully as it loads the project on localhost.

---

Here is my MAMP settings:

[image]

[image]

And the `test` database is created (with tables in it which I have previously created and used in my other projects, not Laravel.)

[image]

---

Even though everything seems correct to me, when trying to submit Auth form, I am getting this error:

> #### PDOException in Connector.php line 50:
>   could not find driver
>
> 1. in Connector.php line 50
> 2. at PDO->__construct ('mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname=test', 'root', 'root', array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in Connector.php line 50
> 3. at Connector->createConnection('mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock;dbname=test', array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost:8889', 'database' => 'test', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => 'root', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in MySqlConnector.php line 22
>
> and so on...

Comment: hello which version of MAMP you use?

Comment: @dyachenko hi, 3.0.7.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was pretty simple for me, I added :8889 to the localhost in the .env file.

DB_HOST=localhost:8889

This is because in the MAMP preferences, :8889 is the default port.

Answer (score 15):

On mac or unix you have to include the socket path in the configuration database.php file

i.e `'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',`

Comment: Your answer was helpful to me as I couldn't establish a connection from laravel project to MySQL using mamp, but then I added `DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` to my `.env` file and connection were established. Your answer gave me the idea. thanks and vote up.

Comment: 2020: I'm using MacOS Mojave and this was indeed what I needed to establish a connection

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman Not working for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865114/laravel-remote-db-connection-issue-on-mamp-pro-osx

Comment: @twister_void yeah maybe it's better to just get it all setup in Docker.

Answer (score 6):

The most important thing for me was defining the UNIX socket. Because I have another MYSQL on my machine - Laravel was trying to connect to a database in that MYSQL process.

Defining the UNIX for the MAMP database to be used worked perfectly. Try adding this to your MYSQL configuration in database.php

```
   'mysql' => [
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
      'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
      'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
      'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
      'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
      'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
      'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
      'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      'prefix' => '',
      'strict' => true,
      'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am concerned it doesn't make any sense to set in **database.php** as many of them suggested.

Since this change would be mostly required in the **development mode**. So the proper way of setting the **unix_socket** is as below

file: **.env**

```
DB_SOCKET='/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

By doing the above way already **.env** is included in **.gitignore** and won't create any other problem while your project is remotely deployed.

> NOTE: I have tested this setting in Laravel 5.7 and above versions

Comment: For me, it is not working for doing connections to remote from local laravel copy.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865114/laravel-remote-db-connection-issue-on-mamp-pro-osx

Answer (score 2):

**Found my answer. Here is a way to fix it:**

- Start MAMP
- On the top left, go to "MAMP" -> "Preferences"
- Go to the "PHP" tab
- Tick PHP 5.5.17 (or whatever you have) instead of the one which is ticked by default (5.6.1 -> 5.5.17 with he latest version of MAMP)