# Running a Laravel project on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, apache, web, phpstorm

Im trying to run already working laravel project (page that works well on cloud) on localhost. Cant figure where is problem.

```
Code editor: PhpStorm (newest version)
Apache: MAMP 2.2.27
```

I want to make some changes in code and I want to see those changes.

> MAMP Ports

[image]

> When I try to Run it via PhpStorm setup

[image]

> PhpStorm Deplyment
>   [image]
>   [image]
>
> My PHP
>   [image]

How do I run this project on localhost? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Have you tried running [`php artisan serve`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#installing-laravel)?

Comment: what exactly did you do? did you copy the files on your local machine? did you use git to cloned the files? are you using windows/Linux/Mac? what is the php on the server?

Comment: Check out [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31541814/4705339)

Comment: Run command `php artisan serve`, then you can see your web page by accessing `http://localhost:8000`. And I guess you didn't read manual to setup laravel projects at https://laravel.com/docs/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running it in PhpStorm on a built-in web server on a default port. Try changing the port for your "web" in-place deployment configuration: web server root url should look like `https://localhost:8888/web`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the project root directory:`php artisan serve`.

If you can visit.
Maybe problem in `apache` config.

Comment: Problem is not in apache..btw php artisan serve I tried as first didnt work :/