# Laravel remote DB connection issue on MAMP Pro OSX

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, macos, mamp

I have an existing project on Laravel. I want to make a connection to remote DB server so our team can test with the same set of data .

.ENV File

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=live
APP_KEY=base64:FE9rhqH/+5UHVJCfoYS6xHNsU9U1DJaPkUDmRSv6JxI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://laravel.test/

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=104.1XX.XX.XX
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=My_db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_username
DB_PASSWORD=db_password
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '104.1XX.XX.XX'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', ''),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'My_db_name'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'db_usernamel'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'db_password'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

**Error shows it is trying to connect to localhost**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException thrown with message "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select `users`.* from `followers` inner join `users` on `followers`.`follower_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `countries` on `users`.`country_id` = `countries`.`id` where (`followers`.`user_id` is null))"
```

**Expected Behaviour: should connect to remote DB**

`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u db_username -h 104.1XX.XX.XX -p`

> Able to make the connection using the above string in terminal

`Laravel Framework 5.8.37`

`PHP 7.3.11 (cli)`

`Mamp Pro - 5.7`

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Why don't you construct tests that pre-populate temp data and share that test with your team? Well, if you're using git then you won't need to share it because it'll be in the project to start with. Tests do not need to be conducted on a remote database to find out if your logic works or not. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/testing

Comment: @Savlon I need to have snapshot of 10 days old always to test some cache test. I was explaining my condition there. I need to test using remote DB but not able to make connection

Comment: have you cleared your cache? php artisan config:cache also run composer dumpautoload

Comment: @Savlon . I think yes , run these command no luck ```php artisan cache:clear``` ```php artisan config:clear``` ```composer dumpauto```

Comment: php artisan cache:clear is different to php artisan cache:config

Comment: I tried all above but nothing works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210369/discussion-between-savlon-and-twister-void).

Answer (score 0):

As per your error its not the problem of Laravel project. Its the problem of your database. You cannot access the database outside of the server where it is deployed.

Possible problems are as follows:

```
1. Database user configured to access only for localhost and not outside

2. Proper database credentials
```

For 1 you can use the following

```
% -> stands for anywhere
```

Basically with the below your giving all the access to the user USERNAME to access from anywhere in the world

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Along with the above make sure to do the following

change **bind-address** in file **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf**

Basically it will be **127.0.0.1** or your server ip-address change it to **0.0.0.0**

Hope it works for you. Cheers.

Comment: If you read my question properly it is already mentioned I am able to make a connection.
Mac OSX terminal, using Data Grip I am able to make a connection in Windows the same .env is working. So I think there is no problem in connecting to Database from Outside